# Thumbnails in ember template

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, ember.js

Im building my first ember application which has a user template. It displays my list of users by name. I would like them to be displayed as a group of thumbnails instead, using their avatar picture.

```
<script type = "text/x-handlebars" id = "users">
<div>{{usersCount}}</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
{{#link-to "users.create"}}<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></button> {{/link-to}}
</div>
<div class="col-md-10">

  <ul class="users-listing">
  {{#each user in controller}}
  <li>
    {{#link-to "user" user}}
      {{user.name}}
    {{/link-to}}
  </li>
{{/each}}

</ul>

{{outlet}}
</div>
</script>
```

I have been trying to do this using bootstrap thumbnails but with little success:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
{{#each user in controller}}
    <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
      <img data-src="user.avatar">
{{/each}}
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the docs for [`{{bind-attr}}`](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/binding-element-attributes/):

```
{{#each}}
  <a href="#" class="thumbnail">
    <img {{bind-attr src=avatar}}>
  </a>
{{/each}}
```

Also note that in Bootstrap the `data-src` attribute is only for the placeholder image, not the image you'd like to actually display.